# CSS 3d perspective off

Tags: html, dom, css, perspective

i'm trying to get a hang off the 3d transform functions in css. My code at this point is pretty much copied straight from a tutorial because no matter how hard i try i just cant seem to get it working properly. the link to how it's supposed to look is: http://desandro.github.com/3dtransforms/examples/card-01.html

and my code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style media="screen">      
            .container  {
                width: 200px;
                height: 260px;
                position: relative;
                -webkit-perspective: 800;
                }
            #card {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3D;
                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
                }
            #card figure  {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
                }
            #card .face1  {
                background: red;
                }
            #card .face2  {
                background: blue;
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
                }
            #card:hover  {
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
                }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section class="container">
            <div id="card">
                <figure class="face1">1</figure>
                <figure class="face2">2</figure>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

like i said its pretty much word for word from the tutorial, only thing i changed was using hover instead of a button. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

add `margin: 0` to the `figure`s. The example has an external stylesheet that applies it, so it's not immediately obvious that it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The initialisation of the flip isn't be done with CSS ..  It's done with Javascript via the file "flip-card.js":

```
var init = function() {
  var card = document.getElementById('card');

  document.getElementById('flip').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
    card.toggleClassName('flipped');
  }, false);
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

This needs to be changes to an onHover event handler.

Answer (score 0):

There is a container which contains the figures, to place figures right in the container add rule to them: `margin: 0px;` (in default it is not 0).

Answer (score 0):

Hey there are two files utils.js and flip.js .. include both of them and in your css just use

```
-webkit-transform-style
-moz-transform-style
-o-transform-style
transform-style
```

so that your 3d transform will render in every browser... :)